# How do I get a subgroup percentage of row main group total in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I realize the question is not self-explanatory in the slightest and have a detailed explanation below. I'm trying to create a stacked bar graph in Power BI that essentially shows the percentages of 2 subgroups from their total on their respective row. I've attached a picture below showing what this looks like.

a and b are the same item for each individual. The report is monthly, so this will be filtered on whatever the last month's data is. The totals are the totals of a+b spanning across the three categories; these are the items of importance I have highlighted in green in the totals column. I'm looking to make the stacked bar chart out of only the items in category 3 divided by their respective row/group totalling, and the items in green should be divided by the item in green in the total column

[image]

Below is what I have done manually to obtain these results. I take the green items, make another table, and simply divide them to obtain the percentage.

[image]

I then insert a stacked bar chart and select the person and 2 groupings with the percent values. This graph is my desired end result.

[image]

I have tried at least 8 iterations of measures to no success. Power BI is somewhat new to me and I'm having a hard time translating what I know how to do in Excel to Power BI.

I sincerely appreciate any help you provide me!

Comment: Do Person John and "a" & "b" are there in the same column? If not please show your actual data structure for the sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

= DIVIDE(COUNTA(Categories), CALCULATE(COUNTA(Categories),ALLEXCEPT(Table, Person, Month)))

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the above comment, data structure does not seems in actual format in your sample data. If I guess your sample data in this below structure-

[image]

Now select column **person** and **ab** and apply unpivot other columns as shown below-

[image]

Now, rename the **Attribute** column as **Category** and the end result will be as below-

[image]

Now get back to report by clicking **Close & Apply** button, and create these below 3 measures-

```
percentage_a = 

VAR person_a_cate_3_sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            your_table_name,
            your_table_name[person]
        ),
        your_table_name[category] = "category3"
        && your_table_name[ab] = "a"
    )
)

VAR person_wise_total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Value]),
    ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[person])
)

RETURN person_a_cate_3_sum/person_wise_total
```

```
percentage_b = 

VAR person_b_cate_3_sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            your_table_name,
            your_table_name[person]
        ),
        your_table_name[category] = "category3"
        && your_table_name[ab] = "b"
    )
)

VAR person_wise_total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Value]),
    ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[person])
)

RETURN person_b_cate_3_sum/person_wise_total
```

```
calculating_total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Value]),
    ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[person])
)
```

**Finally**, if we add all above measures in the table visual, the output will be as below-

[image]

**Now for the BAR Chart** Create this below **Measure**

```
percentage_a_b = 

VAR person_a_cate_3_sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            your_table_name,
            your_table_name[person],
            your_table_name[ab]
        ),
        your_table_name[category] = "category3"
    )
)

VAR person_wise_total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Value]),
    ALLEXCEPT(
        your_table_name,
        your_table_name[person]
    )
)

RETURN person_a_cate_3_sum/person_wise_total
```

Now configure the bar chart as below-

[image]

Here is the final output-

[image]